# better way of handling screen rotation in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-spinner, android-screen

For the screen rotation, I've implemented attribute android:ConfigChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest file. Everything works fine. But this  [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)  here suggests to consider this approach to be last resort and not recommended one. 
What would be the better way of handling this screen rotation ? 
(FYI: My app implements multiple spinners to get info from user and then writes to a file. so by default, when a screen rotation happens, i would loose all info that user selected)
help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the better way of handling this screen rotation ?

Delete that attribute.

If you find that you need to pass information from the old activity instance to the new one, on the configuration change, you can put data in the `Bundle` you are passed in `onSaveInstanceState()`, and use that data in `onRestoreInstanceState()` to tailor your UI. In the case of a `Spinner`, you can pass the selected position this way, restoring it in the new activity.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
I am working on that.
I've removed that attribute; since my app has two activities & whenever user is in activity-2 and rotated the screen, the app restarts and activity-1 is being shown. 
How do I load the same activity again ?

Comment: @nani: "the app restarts and activity-1 is being shown" -- you must be doing that yourself, somehow. Android does not do that.